# How to use a regex to match a pattern which does not have a specific string at the end

Tags: grep, regular-expression

How can I use a "POSIX BRE" or a "POSIX ERE" regex to match a string
(line or word) that does ***not*** have `bak` at the end?

I want to do a `ls | egrep '<regex>'` to find all files which DO NOT have `bak` at the end of the filename.

For example, if there are three files `file1`, `file2_bak`, and `bak_file3`, the regex should match only `file1` and `bak_file3` (but not `file2_bak`).

I know that this can be done with `ls | grep -v 'bak$'`, but I want to do this without using `-v` option for `grep` or `egrep`. I don’t want to use `-v` because this is just a theoretical/academic question on POSIX regexes.

This is how I match the filenames which DO HAVE `bak` at the end:

```
$ ls | egrep 'bak$'
file2_bak
$
```

The above regex, `bak$`, matches all strings that DO HAVE `bak` at the end. But how can I write a regex which matches all strings that **do *not* have** `bak` at the end?

Comment: I suggest to make explicit clear in your question that you are asking an **academical** question (as opposed to a practical one), and formulate it accordingly, i.e. without reference to the `ls` or `grep` tools, but only formulated in terms of Regular Expressions. (I seem to have been not the only one misleaded by your question.)

Comment: You should maybe explain why just using `-v` isn't ok (because that's the "normal" way to do what you ask with *grep*).

Comment: @Janis Yes looks like i confused many people.. I edited the question.. maybe someone who reads it in future wont get confused ..

Comment: @hyde Actually my question was on the `regex` part that is why I did not want to use `-v`. It was just a theoretical/academical question on `regex`. As `grep` is the only utility I have used so far to use `regex` my question somehow had a `grep` command in it. For practical puprpose even I will do `-v` and keep it simple and clear. I am practising posix regex so i was just trying different things to test myself ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular languages (i.e. "this can be matched with a RE") are closed under complement, so it's possible, but it's not very useful for practical purposes: what you start out with is the condition

> last letter is `k` AND letter before that is `a` AND letter before that is `b`

(let me write `s[-1]=='k' and s[-2]=='a' and s[-3]=='b'` in a pythonesque fashion)
so a string that fails that has

```
not(s[-1]=='k' and s[-2]=='a' and s[-3]=='b')
```

i.e.

```
not(s[-1]=='k') or not (s[-2]=='a' and s[-3]=='b'))
```

i.e.

```
not(s[-1]=='k') or not(s[-2]=='a') or not(s[-3]=='b')
```

applying deMorgan's rule twice, and of course, this would in particular be the case if your string has length 2 or less, so you would roughly end up with

```
grep '^$\|^.$\|^..$\|..[^k]$\|.[^a].$\|[^b]..$'
```

which I'd consider typeable but unmaintainable.

(Theoretical sidenote: in general, you'd convert your regular expression into a deterministic finite automaton (DFA), invert the terminal states there, and then convert the new DFA back into a regular expression, which is all well-defined, but a somewhat tedious and error-prone process.)

Comment: This is what I trying to come up with. Although I do not about deMorgan rule or few other things you said above, but I understood the command `grep '^$\|^.$\|^..$\|..[^k]$\|.[^a].$\|[^b]..$'`. With `egrep` no need to escape `|`.          `ls | egrep '^$|^.$|^..$|..[^k]$|.[^a].$|[^b]..$'`  . Answer by @.kos has a `pcre` answer which does similar to what i was asking for. I was thinking i could do that way without using any options for `grep`.

Comment: POSIX BREs have no `\|`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, there is no `|` alternating character in `BRE`. I am just learning it and found out that, in the gnu version of `grep`, if we escape a `ERE` metacahracter (which is not a metacharacter of `BRE`) with a baskslash then they get the meaning which they have in `ERE`. So if we put a '\' before any of these `| ( ) ? + { }` then they get their meaning which they have in usual `ERE`. I dont know if that is a feature only of the `gnu grep` or it is also a standard for `BRE`. Just learning now and i maybe wrong though..

Comment: @sps, yes for GNU tools BRE and ERE are the same thing with different syntax. GNU grep is found on quite a few systems. For instance, many BSDs had GNU grep for a while (until they rewrote their own (backward compatible) one. The POSIX spec is [there](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html). Note that things like `\{`were added to BREs before EREs (`{`).

Answer (score 5):

If you use `ksh` (or `bash` with *[extended globbing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob)* activated, or `zsh` with *[ksh globs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-KSHGLOB)* enabled) you can achieve the desired function using only file globbing patterns:

```
ls -d -- !(*bak)
```

With `grep`, to get a simple solution, just use the negation `-v`:

```
ls | grep -v 'bak$'
```

Comment: Works also for `bash`- I don't know how I couldn't think of it.

Answer (score 3):

Using `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name "*bak"
```

- `.`: asserts to search in the current working directory
- `-maxdepth 1`: asserts to search only one level below the specified directory (i.e. only the current working directory)
- `-type f`: asserts to search only for files
- `! -name "*bak"`: asserts to search only for filenames not ending in `bak`

However, if you want to `grep` `ls`'s output:

```
ls | grep -v 'bak$'
```

- `-v`: prints only the lines not matching the given regex

**Regex breakdown**:

- `bak`: matches a `bak` string
- `$`: matches the end of the line

The same using negative look-behind (for `PCRE`s-compatible `grep` versions):

```
ls | grep -P '(?<!bak)$'
```

- `-P`: matches lines using `PCRE`s

**Regex breakdown**:

- `(?<!bak)`: only matches the following pattern if not preceded by a `bak` string
- `$`: matches the end of the line

Comment: @kos Thanks +1 for the help. But I want to do it using `ls | grep` or `ls | egrep` , and not by using `find`. My question is about the `regex` and not the utility (`find` or `grep` etc)...

Comment: @sps See the update. However, I'd still suggest you to use `find` instead of using `ls`. `ls`'s output easily breaks when parsing it, while `find`'s output can be more robust.

Comment: @mikeserv Thanks for the notice. Never used `-prune`, so I'm looking into that right now.

Comment: @kos Thanks again. And i took a note on using `find` - good suggestion. But again here my question is about the `regex`. Only the part which is inside the single quotes `' '`. I dont want to use `-v` option. I am sure there is a way .. i just dont know how so i posted here ....

Comment: @kos - i disagree - `find`'s output is not more robust. Any issues one might have with handling a stream from `ls` might also occur handling a stream from `find`. But you can do `find ... -exec`, which is nice. To get names on separate lines from the data w/ `ls` you can make a symlink to `.` named for a `\n`ewline and use `-d` and globs. With `find` you must do similar stuff w/ `.//.` and so on the reliably anchor output lines *(though those are uncertain for symlinks, too)*. The `printf` thing was dumb though huh? This is a request for the complement - you can't do that w/ a standard glob.

Comment: @sps Does your `grep` version support `PCRE`s (e.g. like GNU `grep` does)? If so, I can write a regex using a negative lookahead to match only strings not followed by a `bak` string at the end.

Comment: @sps However, I don't understand the need of *not* using `-v`.

Comment: @kos Yes, my system is a debian linux and the grep i am using is a GNU grep.

Comment: @kos I am trying to not use `-v` because I am learning POSIX regex. So I want to learn how to do the above thing just by using regex.

Comment: @mikeserv It's "more roubust" (explicitly hard-quoted) in the sense that it *could be* easier parsable by third-party tools (however I agree that newlines in the middle of the filename would be still a pain in the neck). But still, a little better than `ls`.

Comment: @sps The only way I can think of for doing this without using `-v` is to use a negative look-ahead. Is this supported by your `grep` version?

Comment: @kos How to find that out ? My grep is `grep (GNU grep) 2.16`. Also is negative look-ahead POSIX compliant feature ?

Comment: @sps Nevermind, just saw your comment. Going to update

Comment: @kos - how so? `ls`'s output format is specified - there are rules. If you know what you're about you can handle it. When `ls` doesn't write a filename it writes a formatted field - and w/ switches like `-qngd` it gets easier.

Comment: @sps Updated, however I couldn't make it using negative look-ahead, I had to use a negative look-behind. Someone more proficient in `PCRE`s than me perhaps might be able to explain why. In any case I could drop the use of `-v`.

Comment: @mikeserv Indeed, so how would you parse `ls`? This a rethoric and *very* serious question. I'd *love* to be able to do that. What I stated is that, excluding newlines in the middle of the filename, `find [...] -print0` + `IFS=$'\0' while read -r` is perfectly capable to handle the job (again, excluding newlines in the middle of the filename, which are a pain in the neck).

Comment: `find -print0` is better. It's an extension too, which, can be matched in a GNU `ls` by specifying arbitrary terminal escapes via the `dircolors` interface. In fact - you can pair delimiter strings by filetype/extension that way. But youre right about the rhetoric - my point was just that a stream is a stream. Without uniquely reliable - and planned for - stops in input, it's all the same. And anyway, with any path string, there;s always good ole `/`. And `find ... -exec` is best, i think.

Comment: @kos basically you did it, but you did it in the `pcre` which I just read in google that it is `perl compatible regular expression`. I was looking for a basic `posix ere` or a `posix bre` regex. What you did is a `pcre` regex as i understand. nice to know about `pcre` and looks like its much easier in `pcre`. Also look at the answer @.Ulrich has posted if you would like to see how it can be done in `posix bre`. Sorry but it was that answer that i was looking for. But good work, good to know about `pcre` ..  +2three$

Comment: @sps No problem. Feel free to accept the answer you were looking for, however maybe next time be clear about the requirements! Ulrich Schwarz's answer is great and indeed deserves an acceptance (I honestly couldn't have make it using `BRE`s)

Comment: @kos but i guess its better to use  `pcre` . It looks we need to type less with `pcre`. I dont know anything about `pcre` now. Note for the future .! I guess these comments need to stop here..

Answer (score 1):

With POSIX BREs that have no alternation operator, you can use that `\{0,1\}` instead:

```
LC_ALL=C grep '^\.\{0,2\}\(.*[^k]\)\{0,1\}\(.*[^a].\)\{0,1\}\(.*[^b]..\)\{0,1\}$'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have perl extensions, you can use negative look ahead.

```
grep -P '^.{0,2}$|^.*(?!bak)...$'
```

For matching a line not ending with bak